# Latency and Throughput Bounds

Tags: terminology, operating-systems

Say that I have a superscalar processor and I am given the latency, issue and capacity (in clock cycles) for different instructions.

**What is the general formula for latency bound and throughput bound?** (I will convert to cost per instruction and billion instructions per second)

This field seems to be too niche to find information online.

In other words, how can I find the latency bound and throughput bound for `fdiv`

```
     Latency   Issue  Capacity
fdiv    L        I       C
```

where `L` is the number of cycles for the `fdiv` latency, `I` for issue and `C` for capacity?

Would $\text{latency bound} = {L \over I} \times C$ and $\text{throughput bound} = {L \over C}$?

This is not the homework problem, but a "required" definition in order to be able to *start* it.